# Input fields in JSP/ Exception occurred processing jsp page

Tags: jsp, exception, spring-mvc

When tryign to create an input field on the jsp page, I get the error: `exception occurred processing jsp page`. Error starts where the form begins. I am not sure what is wrong. I have attached the code on my jsp file below and can be seen by clicking the code link below. Please let me know if it is not visible. Thanks!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpssW.png)

```
@RequestMapping("/addQuizAnswer")
public String addQuizAnswer(HashMap<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("quiz", new Quiz()); 
    System.out.println((map.get("quiz")) + "addQuiz");
    return "listQuiz"; //jsp name 
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitanswer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addquizContact(@ModelAttribute("quiz")
Quiz quiz, BindingResult result,Map<String, Object> map,  HttpServletRequest request) {
    // String someAction(@ModelAttribute("somedata") Somedata data, 
    // Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request){ 
    // map.put("somedata", data); 
    // map.put("age", request.getParameter("age"); 
    // return "somepage"
    memberService.addQuiz(quiz);
    System.out.println(quiz + "submitanswer");
    return "redirect:/check"; 
}

@RequestMapping("/answerList")
public String listanswers(HashMap<String, Object> map) {
    System.out.println("In Here");

    // Fetching values from database
    map.put("answerList", memberService.listQuiz());
    System.out.println(map.get("answerList") + "answerList");
    return "listquiz"; //jsp name
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{QuizAnswersId}")
public String deleteQuizAnswers(@PathVariable("QuizAnswersId")
Integer memberId) {

    //memberService.removeQuizAnswers(QuizAnswersId);
    return "redirect:/memberList";
}
```

Comment: What you have tried. Please post your total jsp page Code.

Comment: The jsp page can be viewed on the file attached above. I have also posted the code from my controller for further reference. The class QuizAnswers has the attributes : answerone, answertwo, answerthree, and name. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace in log file?